# Process Synchronization and failure of Peterson's Method

Tags: process, operating-system, synchronization, busy-waiting

Peterson's solution may fail in modern architectures due to a features introduced known as reordering. It just means if two instructions are independent then the processor can execute
them in any order. So if the first two statements in the entry section of the Peterson's solution are interchanged then what criteria of a correct synchronization mechanism it may violate or fail to hold ?
The criteria are :

1)Mutual exclusion

2)Progress

3)Bounded wait